# How are passwords stored using the Sonarqube LDAP plugin savePassword option?

Tags: ldap, sonarqube

The LDAP plugin for Sonarqube (http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/LDAP+Plugin) has the security.savePassword option:

> sonar.security.savePassword
>
> To save the user password in the SonarQube database. Then, users will be able to log into SonarQube even when the LDAP server is not reachable.

The plugin page has no information on how these passwords are stored - are they encrypted or stored as plain-text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any user password stored in SonarQube is stored as a sha1 hash with some random salt.